# Welche Wörter beginnen mit wider / mit wieder und wo liegt der Unterschied?

Tags: word-usage, verb, spelling

Es gibt einige deutsche Wörter, v.a. Verben, welche mit

"wider..." beginnen (z.b. **widersagen, widerlegen, widerfahren**) und andere mit

"wieder..." (z.B. **wiederholen, wiederspiegeln**) usw.

Comment: https://www.korrekturen.de/beliebte_fehler/wiederspiegeln.shtml

Comment: answered here: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46645/german-equivalents-to-the-prefix-re/46653#46653

Answer (score 5):

### wider

bedeutet "gegen", "entgegen", "dagegen" ...

### wieder

bedeutet "nochmal", "ein zweites Mal" ...

---

Nachdem ausdrücklich gefragt wurde

> **Welche Wörter beginnen mit wider / mit wieder ...**

muss eine korrekte Antwort auch die verlangten Wortlisten bereitstellen.

Für beide Aufzählungen gilt: Die häufig verwendeten Wörter stehen am Beginn der Liste, die seltenen am Ende der Liste:

### wider

Widerstand, widersprechen, Widerspruch, wider, widerlegen, widersetzen, widerspiegeln, widersprüchlich, widerstehen, widerfahren, Widerstandskämpfer, widerrufen, Widersacher, widerlich, widerrechtlich, widerspenstig, widerstandsfähig, widerwillig, Wider, Widerruf, Widersprüchlichkeit, Widerstandsbewegung, Widerstandsgruppe, widern, widersinnig, widersprechend, Widerstreit, Widerwille, widerstandslos, widerstreben, widerstrebend, widerwärtig, Widerhall, Widerlegung, Widerpart, Widerstandsfähigkeit, widerborstig, Widerstandskraft, Widerstandskämpferin, widerlegt, widersetzt, widerspruchsfrei, widerspruchslos, Widerständler, Widerwillen, widerstreitend, widerständig, Widerhaken, Widerlager, Widerrede, Widerrufsrecht, Widerschein, Widerspruchsverfahren, widerhallen, widerlegbar, widernatürlich, Widerstandsnest, Widerstandsorganisation, Widerstandsrecht, Widerstreben, Widerwort, Widerwärtigkeit, widerstreiten, Widerhandlung, Widersacherin, Widersinn, Widerspiegelung, Widerspruchsrecht, Widerstandsaktion, Widerstandsarmee, Widerstandsgeist, Widerstandshandlung, Widerstandskampf, Widerstandskreis, Widerstandsrat, Widerstandswille, Widerstandswillen, Widerständigkeit, widerspruchsvoll, widerstandsunfähig, Widerborstigkeit, Widerristhöhe, Widerrufsfrist, Widerspenstigkeit, Widerspiel, Widerspruchsfreiheit, Widerspruchsfrist, Widerspruchsgeist, Widerspruchslösung, Widerstandsform, Widerstandsklasse, Widerstandslinie, widerrufbar, Widerstandspotenzial, widerruflich, Widerstandszone, Widerklage, Widerlichkeit, Widerling, Widerrist, Widerrufsbelehrung, Widersetzlichkeit, Widersinnigkeit, Widerspruchsbescheid, Widerspruchsführer, Widerspruchsklausel, Widerspruchsmöglichkeit, Widerspruchsregelung, Widerspruchsstelle, Widerstandkämpfer, Widerstandsarbeit, Widerstandscamp, Widerstandsfront, Widerstandsführer, Widerstandsgeschichte, Widerstandskoalition, widergespiegelt, Widerstandskultur, widersagen, widerscheinen, widersetzlich, Widerstandszelle, widerstandlos, widerstehend, widerständisch, Widerrufung, Widerspruchsausschuss, Widerstandsaktivität, Widerstandsbegriff, Widerstandshaltung, Widerstandsheld, Widerstandskomitee, widerklingen, Widerstandslied, Widerstandslosigkeit, widerraten, Widerstandstag, Widerstandstruppe, Widerstandsunfähigkeit, Widerstandszentrum, widerspruchlos, Widerständlerin, Widerwertigkeit, widerstrahlen, Widerdruck, Widerklang, Widerlegungsversuch, Widerrechtlichkeit, Widerrufsvorbehalt, Widerspiegelungstheorie, Widerstandsanstieg, Widerstandsfraktion, Widerstandskonzept, widerleglich, Widerstandsliteratur, widerreden, Widerstandspartei, Widerstandsregierung, Widerstandstradition, widerständlerisch, widervernünftig, Widernatürlichkeit, Widerrufsklage, Widerspruchslosigkeit, Widerstandsallianz, Widerstandsdorf, Widerstandskampagne, widereinander, widergesetzlich, widermenschlich, Widerstandspflicht, widerschallen, Widervernunft, Widerchrist, Widerhalt, Widerspruchsklage, widerdeutsch, widergeistig, widersacherisch, Widerstandsmesser

### wieder

wiederholen, wiederum, wiederholt, Wiederholung, Wiedervereinigung, Wiederwahl, Wiederaufbau, wiedergeben, wiederwählen, Wiederherstellung, Wiedersehen, Wiederaufnahme, wiederfinden, wiederherstellen, wiederkehrend, Wiedergutmachung, Wiederanpfiff, wiederbeleben, Wiederaufstieg, wiederentdecken, wiedererkennen, Wiederbelebung, Wiedereinführung, wiederkehren, wiederkommen, wiedersehen, Wiedereröffnung, Wiedergabe, Wiedergeburt, Wiederholungstäter, Wiederkehr, wiederaufbauen, wiederaufnehmen, wiederaufsteigen, Wiederbeginn, Wiedereingliederung, wiedereröffnen, Wiedereinstieg, wiedergewählt, Wiederentdeckung, Wiederholungsspiel, Wiederinbetriebnahme, Wiederstein, Wiederverwertung, Wiedervorlage, Wiederaufarbeitung, Wiederaufarbeitungsanlage, Wiederaufbereitungsanlage, Wiederauferstehung, wiedererlangen, Wiederbelebungsversuch, wiedererstarkt, wiedergewinnen, wiedergewonnen, Wiedereintritt, wiedergutmachen, Wiedereinzug, wiederhergestellt, Wiedererrichtung, wiedervereinigt, Wiedergänger, Wiederholen, Wiederholungsfall, Wiederholungsgefahr, Wiederkäuer, wiederauferstehen, Wiederverwendung, Wiederansiedlung, wiederaufgebaut, Wiederveröffentlichung, Wiederzulassung, Wiederaufbauhilfe, wiederaufleben, Wiederaufbereitung, wiederbekommen, wiederbelebt, Wiederaufforstung, Wiederaufführung, Wiederauflage, Wiederaufleben, wiederentdeckt, Wiederbegegnung, Wiederbesetzung, wiedererstehen, Wiederbetätigung, Wiederbewaffnung, wiedergeboren, wiedergefunden, wiedergegeben, wiedergegründet, Wiedereinsetzung, Wiedereinsteiger, wiedergenesen, Wiedereinstellung, wiederhaben, wiederholbar, Wiedererkennungswert, Wiedererlangung, wiederkäuen, wiedertreffen, wiedervereinigen, wiederverwendbar, wiederverwenden, Wiedergewinnung, Wiedergründung, wiederverwertbar, wiederverwerten, Wiederholungskurs, Wiederholungsprüfung, Wiederhören, Wiederkandidatur, Wiederkunft, Wiedersehensfreude, Wiedertäufer, Wiederabstieg, Wiederverkauf, Wiederverkäufer, Wiederanfahren, wiederauferstanden, Wiederannäherung, Wiederaufbauarbeit, wiederauftauchen, Wiederaufbauprogramm, Wiederaufbauteam, Wiederaufflammen, wiederbesetzen, Wiederaufnahmeverfahren, wiedererkennbar, Wiederbelebungsmaßnahme, Wiederbeschaffung, wiedererrichten, wiedererrichtet, wiedererstanden, wiedererstarken, wiedererwachen, wiedererwecken, wiedereröffnet, Wiedereinreise, Wiedereinsteigerin, Wiedereinweihung, Wiedererkennen, Wiedererkennungseffekt, Wiedererstarken, wiedervereint, wiederverheiratet, wiederverwendet, wiederverwertet, wiederveröffentlichen, wiederveröffentlicht, Wiederheirat, Wiederherstellungschirurgie, Wiederholbarkeit, Wiederholer, Wiederholungstat, Wiederholungswahl, Wiederholungszwang, Wiederlesen, Wiedersehensfeier, Wiederverheiratung, wiederanfahren, Wiederverkaufswert, wiederaufbereiten, wiederaufbereitet, wiederaufgenommen, Wiederöffnung, wiederaufladbar, Wiederaufbauplan, Wiederaufbauprojekt, wiederbegegnen, wiederbeschaffen, wiederbeschreibbar, wiederbringen, wiedereinführen, Wiederaufrüstung, Wiederaufsteiger, Wiederaufstellung, wiedereinsetzen, wiedererkannt, Wiederbegründung, wiedererlangt, Wiederbeschaffungswert, Wiederbesetzungssperre, Wiederbesiedlung, Wiederbestellung, wiedererwacht, Wiedereinbürgerung, Wiedereinrichtung, wiedergründen, Wiederentdecker, wiederherrichten, Wiedererkennbarkeit, Wiedererkennung, wiederhören, Wiedereroberung, wiederstehen, Wiedererwachen, Wiedererweckung, wiedervereinen, Wiedergabedauer, Wiedergutmachungsleistung, Wiedergutmachungszahlung, Wiedergängerin, Wiederherstellungsarbeit, Wiederholungstäterin, Wiederinstandsetzung, Wiedervereinigungsboom, Wiederabdruck, Wiederaneignung, Wiedervernässung, Wiederversöhnung, Wiederverwendbarkeit, wiederauffinden, Wiederverwertbarkeit, Wiederanschluss, wiederaufführen, Wiederansiedelung, wiederaufgearbeitet, Wiederansiedlungsprojekt, wiederaufgeflammt, Wiederanstieg, wiederaufgelegt, wiederaufgreifen, wiederaufheben, Wiederaufbaumaßnahme, Wiederaufbauphase, Wiederaufbauzeit, wiederbegründen, Wiederauffinden, Wiederauffindung, wiederbesiedeln, wiederbestellen, wiedereingeführt, Wiederaufnahmeantrag, Wiederaufrichtung, Wiederaufschwung, Wiederaufstockung, wiedereinstellen, Wiederauftreten, wiederentstehen, wiedererhalten, Wiederbegründer, wiedererleben, Wiederbelegung, wiedererobern, Wiederbeschaffungskosten, Wiederbeschäftigung, wiedererscheinen, wiedererwachend, Wiederbewaldung, wiedererweckt, Wiedereingliederungshilfe, Wiedereingliederungsmaßnahme, Wiedereinrichter, wiedergekehrt, wiedergetroffen, Wiedereinstellungszusage, wiederhergerichtet, wiederlesen, Wiedererscheinen, Wiedererteilung, Wiedererwägungsgesuch, Wiedergabegerät, wiederverheiraten, wiederverschließbar, Wiedergenesung, Wiederherrichtung, Wiederhersteller, Wiederherstellungskosten, Wiederholungsfalle, Wiederholungskonzert, Wiederholungsschleife, Wiederholungstermin, Wiederkaufsrecht, Wiederkehrer, Wiedernutzung, Wiedersehensfest, Wiedertaufe, Wiedervereinigungsgebot, Wiedervereinigungspolitik, Wiedervereinigungsprozess, Wiedervergeltung, wiederaufarbeiten, Wiederverkörperung, Wiedervermietung, Wiederanfang, Wiederverstaatlichung, Wiederankurbelung, wiederaufforsten, Wiederverwertungsquote, Wiederverzauberung, Wiederanstellung, wiederaufgehoben, Wiederanstoß, Wiederwahlchance, Wiederaufarbeitungsfirma, wiederaufgetaucht, Wiederaufarbeitungsvertrag, Wiederaufbaujahr, Wiederaufbaukosten, wiederaufrichten, Wiederaufbauleistung, wiederauftreten, wiederbegegnet, wiederbegründet, Wiederaufflackern, Wiederauffüllung, wiedereinbauen, wiedereingesetzt, wiedereingestellt, wiedereinscheren, wiederentstanden, Wiederausbruch, wiedererbaut, Wiederberufung, Wiederbesinnung, wiedererzählen, Wiedereingliederungsprogramm, Wiedereinsatz, Wiedereinscheren, wiedergekäut, Wiedereintrittsstelle, wiederherstellbar, Wiederernennung, wiederkriegen, Wiedererstarkung, wiederschenken, Wiedererstehung, Wiedererwerb, Wiedergabequalität, wiederverkaufen, Wiedergewinn, Wiedergutmachungsabkommen, Wiedergutmachungsanspruch, Wiedergutmachungsgesetz, wiederöffnen, Wiedergutmachungsverfahren, Wiederholungsbefragung, Wiederholungsimpfung, Wiederholungsprozess, Wiederholungszeichen, Wiederverarbeitung, Wiedervereiniger, Wiedervereinigungsfeier, Wiedervereinigungsfrage, Wiedervereinigungspartei, Wiedervereinigungsplan, Wiedervereinigungsrhetorik, wiederabdrucken, Wiederanbringung, Wiederanerkennung, Wiederangliederung, Wiederanknüpfung, Wiederanlaufen, wiederaufflackern, Wiederverwerter, wiederaufflammend, Wiederverwertungsanlage, Wiederanspiel, wiederaufgeforstet, wiederaufgegriffen, Wiederzusammenführung, wiederaufgestellt, wiederaufkeimen, wiederaufkeimend, Wiederaufbaugeneration, wiederaufkommen, Wiederaufbaukonferenz, Wiederaufforstungsprogramm, Wiederaufforstungsprojekt, Wiederaufkommen, wiedereingegliedert, wiedereingeweiht, wiedereingliedern, Wiederaussöhnung, wiedererinnern, Wiederbeitritt, wiedererlernen, Wiederbeschaffungspreis, wiedererschaffen, Wiederbestattung, Wiedereinreiseverbot, wiedergelesen, Wiedereinstellungsgarantie, Wiedereinstiegsstipendium, Wiederentstehung, Wiedererhebung, Wiedererlernen, wiederkennen, Wiedererschaffung, wiederlieben, Wiedergabetechnik, Wiedergesundung, Wiedergutmachungsforderung, Wiedergutmachungsgeld, Wiedergutmachungsregelung, Wiederholungsprogramm, Wiederholungssendung, Wiederholungsverfahren, Wiederinbesitznahme, Wiederinkraftsetzung, Wiederkehroption, Wiederkäuermagen, Wiedersehensszene, Wiedervereinigungsdebatte, Wiedervereinigungseuphorie, Wiedervereinigungskanzler, Wiedervereinigungsparole, Wiedervereinigungstaumel, wiederangelegt, wiederanlaufen, Wiederanfahrgenehmigung, wiederauferstehend, wiederaufgelebt, Wiederaufarbeiter, Wiederaufarbeitungsabfall, Wiederzusammenlegung, wiederaufgerollt, Wiederaufarbeitungsverbot, wiederaufwärmen, wiederbefüllt, wiederbesiedelt, wiederbewaffnen, wiederbewaffnet, wiedereinrichten, Wiederauftritt, Wiederaufwärmen, wiedererobert, wiedererstatten, wiedererwerben, Wiedereinsteigen, wiedergeschenkt, wiedergeöffnet, Wiederergreifung, wiederkaufen, Wiedererstattung, Wiedergabetreue, wiederzugelassen, Wiederholz, Wiederkäufer, Wiedervereinigungsdiskussion, Wiedervereinigungsgerede, Wiedervereinigungsgeschrei, Wiedervereinigungstraum, Wiederanschaffung, Wiederverwertungskonzept, Wiedereinpflanzung, wiedervereinigungsgläubig, wiederverwandt, Wiedergutmachungsamt, Wiederimpfung, wiedersagen, wiedertun, wiederverwendungsfähig, wiederfordern,

Comment: Der Klassiker der Rechtschreibregeln. Da erinnere ich mich automatisch wieder an meine Lehrerin aus der Grundschule und wie sie uns wieder und wieder - wider den Widerstand mancher Mitschüler - den Unterschied erklärt hat.

Comment: Sorry, but I don’t think such a (absurdly?) long list of examples makes your answer better. IMHO it distracts from the core message.

Comment: Including words derived from derived words seems pointless: *widersprechen* suffices, no need to mention *Widerspruch*, *widerspruchslos*, *Widerspruchslosigkeit* as well.

Comment: Das ist ein bisschen viel Empirie.

Comment: Die Frage lautet: "Welche Wörter beginnen mit ... und wo liegt der Unterschied?" Insofern sind die langen Listen durchaus gerechtfertigt.

Comment: @Stephie: Ich habe meine Antwort etwas umstrukturiert und habe nun etwas eingefügt, das ich meinerseits eigentlich für absurd halte, nämlich eine Rechtfertigung dafür, warum ich die gestellte Frage beantwortet habe.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast „welche“ kann man ebenso durch die Zugehörigkeit zu einer Gruppe oder Klasse beantworten statt einer dank Komposita und Ableitungen zwangsläufig unvollständigen Liste. Das hatte ich mit meinem ersten Kommentar impliziert sagen wollen.

Answer (score 5):

Wo liegt der Unterschied? Etymologisch gesehen liegt er in künstlicher Spitzfindigkeit. Die Unterscheidung wurde nämlich von Grammatikern im 17./18. Jahrhundert erfunden (vgl. [wi[e]der – DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/wieder#etymwb-1)).

In der gesprochenen Sprache haben die rein orthografisch getrennten Wortbilder zu allen Zeiten eine identische Aussprache gehabt. In diesem Sinn kann man also sagen, es handle sich um ein einziges Wort mit zwei verschiedenen Schreibungen.

Im Mittelhochdeutschen war das Wort *wider.* Im Neuhochdeutschen ist es mit Dehnung des Vokals in offener Tonsilbe zu /ˈʋiːdər/ geworden. In Dialekten, wo das *ie* nicht zu einem langen /iː/ geworden ist, wird das Wort nie mit *ie* ausgesprochen (vgl. z.B. schweizerdeutsch *wider* /ˈʋɪdər/).

Die Künstlichkeit der Unterscheidung zeigt sich auch in Wörtern wie *widergeben* oder *widerspiegeln,* wo der Bedeutungsunterschied nicht so klar ist. Eine «Widerspiegelung» stellt sich zwar dem Original *entgegen* (dieser Bedeutungsaspekt spricht für die Schreibung ohne *ie),* aber ebensosehr zeigt sie das Original *noch einmal* (dieser Bedeutungsaspekt spräche eigentlich für die Schreibung mit *ie).* Solche unklare Fälle muss man also einfach auswendig lernen.

---

Ähnliche künstliche Unterscheidungen sind *das/dass* oder die Gross- und Kleinschreibung von Substantiven sowie «Substantivierungen» – also die Hauptprobleme der deutschen Rechtschreibung.